# How to limit the angle rotation for thirdperson controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i have a scenario in which i need to limit the angle rotation for 3rd person controller.Present when i press left and right input keys it is turning 90degrees. I wish to rotate 45degrees. Could someone help me,at which line that angle rotation is happening.

Here my code :

```
public class ThirdPersonShooter : MonoBehaviour
{

    public AnimationClip idleAnimation;
    public AnimationClip walkAnimation;
    public AnimationClip runAnimation;
    public AnimationClip jumpPoseAnimation;

    public float walkMaxAnimationSpeed = 0.75F;
    public float trotMaxAnimationSpeed = 1F;
    public float runMaxAnimationSpeed = 1F;
    public float jumpAnimationSpeed = 1F;
    public float landAnimationSpeed = 1F;

    private Animation _animation;

    enum CharacterState
    {
        Idle = 0,
        Walking = 1,
        Trotting = 2,
        Running = 3,
        Jumping = 4,
    }
    private CharacterState _characterState;
    // The speed when walking
    public float walkSpeed = 2.0F;
    // after trotAfterSeconds of walking we trot with trotSpeed
    public float trotSpeed = 4.0F;
    // when pressing "Fire3" button (cmd) we start running
    public float runSpeed = 6.0F;

    public float inAirControlAcceleration = 3.0F;

    // How high do we jump when pressing jump and letting go immediately
    public float jumpHeight = 0.5F;

    // The gravity for the character
    public float gravity = 20.0F;
    // The gravity in controlled descent mode
    public float speedSmoothing = 10.0F;
    public float rotateSpeed = 500.0F;
    public float trotAfterSeconds = 3.0F;

    public bool canJump = true;

    private float jumpRepeatTime = 0.05F;
    private float jumpTimeout = 0.15F;
    private float groundedTimeout = 0.25F;

    // The camera doesnt start following the target immediately but waits for a split second to avoid too much waving around.
    private float lockCameraTimer = 0.0F;

    // The current move direction in x-z
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    // The current vertical speed
    private float verticalSpeed = 0.0F;
    // The current x-z move speed
    private float moveSpeed = 0.0F;

    // The last collision flags returned from controller.Move
    private CollisionFlags collisionFlags;

    // Are we jumping? (Initiated with jump button and not grounded yet)
    private bool jumping = false;
    private bool jumpingReachedApex = false;

    // Are we moving backwards (This locks the camera to not do a 180 degree spin)
    private bool movingBack = false;
    // Is the user pressing any keys?
    private bool isMoving = false;
    // When did the user start walking (Used for going into trot after a while)
    private float walkTimeStart = 0.0F;
    // Last time the jump button was clicked down
    private float lastJumpButtonTime = -10.0F;
    // Last time we performed a jump
    private float lastJumpTime = -1.0F;


    // the height we jumped from (Used to determine for how long to apply extra jump power after jumping.)
    private float lastJumpStartHeight = 0.0F;


    private Vector3 inAirVelocity = Vector3.zero;

    private float lastGroundedTime = 0.0F;


    private bool isControllable = true;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

        _animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
        if (!_animation)
            Debug.Log("The character you would like to control doesn't have animations. Moving her might look weird.");

        /*
    public AnimationClip idleAnimation;
    public AnimationClip walkAnimation;
    public AnimationClip runAnimation;
    public AnimationClip jumpPoseAnimation;
        */
        if (!idleAnimation)
        {
            _animation = null;
            Debug.Log("No idle animation found. Turning off animations.");
        }
        if (!walkAnimation)
        {
            _animation = null;
            Debug.Log("No walk animation found. Turning off animations.");
        }
        if (!runAnimation)
        {
            _animation = null;
            Debug.Log("No run animation found. Turning off animations.");
        }
        if (!jumpPoseAnimation  && canJump) {
            _animation = null;
            Debug.Log("No jump animation found and the character has canJump enabled. Turning off animations.");
        }

    }
    void UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection()
    {
        Transform cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
        bool grounded = IsGrounded();

        // Forward vector relative to the camera along the x-z plane   
        Vector3 forward = cameraTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        forward.y = 0;
        forward = forward.normalized;

        // Right vector relative to the camera
        // Always orthogonal to the forward vector
        Vector3 right = new Vector3(forward.z, 0, -forward.x);

        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        // Are we moving backwards or looking backwards
        if (v < -0.2f)
            movingBack = true;
        else
            movingBack = false;

        bool wasMoving = isMoving;
        isMoving = Mathf.Abs(h) > 0.1f || Mathf.Abs(v) > 0.1f;

        // Target direction relative to the camera
        Vector3 targetDirection = h * right + v * forward;

        // Grounded controls
        if (grounded)
        {
            // Lock camera for short period when transitioning moving  standing still
            lockCameraTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (isMoving != wasMoving)
                lockCameraTimer = 0.0f;

            // We store speed and direction seperately,
            // so that when the character stands still we still have a valid forward direction
            // moveDirection is always normalized, and we only update it if there is user input.
            if (targetDirection != Vector3.zero)
            {
                // If we are really slow, just snap to the target direction
                if (moveSpeed < walkSpeed * 0.9f && grounded)
            {
                    moveDirection = targetDirection.normalized;
                }
            // Otherwise smoothly turn towards it
            else
            {
                    moveDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(moveDirection, targetDirection, rotateSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad * Time.deltaTime, 1000);

                    moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized;
                }
            }

            // Smooth the speed based on the current target direction
            float curSmooth = speedSmoothing * Time.deltaTime;

            // Choose target speed
            //* We want to support analog input but make sure you cant walk faster diagonally than just forward or sideways
            float targetSpeed = Mathf.Min(targetDirection.magnitude, 1.0f);

            _characterState = CharacterState.Idle;

            // Pick speed modifier
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
            {
                targetSpeed *= runSpeed;
                _characterState = CharacterState.Running;
            }
            else if (Time.time - trotAfterSeconds > walkTimeStart)
            {
                targetSpeed *= trotSpeed;
                _characterState = CharacterState.Trotting;
            }
            else
            {
                targetSpeed *= walkSpeed;
                _characterState = CharacterState.Walking;
            }

            moveSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(moveSpeed, targetSpeed, curSmooth);

            // Reset walk time start when we slow down
            if (moveSpeed < walkSpeed * 0.3f)
                walkTimeStart = Time.time;
        }
        // In air controls
        else
        {
            // Lock camera while in air
            if (jumping)
                lockCameraTimer = 0.0f;

            if (isMoving)
                inAirVelocity += targetDirection.normalized * Time.deltaTime * inAirControlAcceleration;
        }



    }
    void ApplyJumping()
    {
        // Prevent jumping too fast after each other
        if (lastJumpTime + jumpRepeatTime > Time.time)
            return;

        if (IsGrounded())
        {
            // Jump
            // - Only when pressing the button down
            // - With a timeout so you can press the button slightly before landing    
            if (canJump && Time.time < lastJumpButtonTime + jumpTimeout) {
                verticalSpeed = CalculateJumpVerticalSpeed(jumpHeight);
                SendMessage("DidJump", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
        }
    }
    void ApplyGravity()
    {
        if (isControllable) // don't move player at all if not controllable.
        {
            // Apply gravity
            bool jumpButton = Input.GetButton("Jump");


            // When we reach the apex of the jump we send out a message
            if (jumping && !jumpingReachedApex && verticalSpeed <= 0.0f)
        {
                jumpingReachedApex = true;
                SendMessage("DidJumpReachApex", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }

            if (IsGrounded())
                verticalSpeed = 0.0f;
            else
                verticalSpeed -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
    float CalculateJumpVerticalSpeed(float targetJumpHeight)
    {
        // From the jump height and gravity we deduce the upwards speed
        // for the character to reach at the apex.
        return Mathf.Sqrt(2 * targetJumpHeight * gravity);
    }
    void DidJump()
    {
        jumping = true;
        jumpingReachedApex = false;
        lastJumpTime = Time.time;
        //lastJumpStartHeight = transform.position.y;
        lastJumpButtonTime = -10;

        _characterState = CharacterState.Jumping;
    }
    void Update()
    {

        if (!isControllable)
        {
            // kill all inputs if not controllable.
            Input.ResetInputAxes();
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            lastJumpButtonTime = Time.time;
        }

        UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection();

        // Apply gravity
        // - extra power jump modifies gravity
        // - controlledDescent mode modifies gravity
        ApplyGravity();

        // Apply jumping logic
        ApplyJumping();

        // Calculate actual motion
        Vector3 movement = moveDirection * moveSpeed + new Vector3(0, verticalSpeed, 0) + inAirVelocity;
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;

        // Move the controller
        CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        collisionFlags = controller.Move(movement);

        // ANIMATION sector
        if (_animation)
        {
            if (_characterState == CharacterState.Jumping)
            {
                if (!jumpingReachedApex)
                {
                    _animation[jumpPoseAnimation.name].speed = jumpAnimationSpeed;
                    _animation[jumpPoseAnimation.name].wrapMode = WrapMode.ClampForever;
                    _animation.CrossFade(jumpPoseAnimation.name);
                }
                else
                {
                    _animation[jumpPoseAnimation.name].speed = -landAnimationSpeed;
                    _animation[jumpPoseAnimation.name].wrapMode = WrapMode.ClampForever;
                    _animation.CrossFade(jumpPoseAnimation.name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (controller.velocity.sqrMagnitude < 0.1f)
                {
                    _animation.CrossFade(idleAnimation.name);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_characterState == CharacterState.Running)
                    {
                        _animation[runAnimation.name].speed = Mathf.Clamp(controller.velocity.magnitude, 0.0f, runMaxAnimationSpeed);
                        _animation.CrossFade(runAnimation.name);
                    }
                    else if (_characterState == CharacterState.Trotting)
                    {
                        _animation[walkAnimation.name].speed = Mathf.Clamp(controller.velocity.magnitude, 0.0f, trotMaxAnimationSpeed);
                        _animation.CrossFade(walkAnimation.name);
                    }
                    else if (_characterState == CharacterState.Walking)
                    {
                        _animation[walkAnimation.name].speed = Mathf.Clamp(controller.velocity.magnitude, 0.0f, walkMaxAnimationSpeed);
                        _animation.CrossFade(walkAnimation.name);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        // ANIMATION sector

        // Set rotation to the move direction
        if (IsGrounded())
        {

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);

        }
        else
        {
            Vector3 xzMove = movement;
            xzMove.y = 0;
            if (xzMove.sqrMagnitude > 0.001f)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(xzMove);
            }
        }

        // We are in jump mode but just became grounded
        if (IsGrounded())
        {
            lastGroundedTime = Time.time;
            inAirVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            if (jumping)
            {
                jumping = false;
                SendMessage("DidLand", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
        }
    }
    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        //  Debug.DrawRay(hit.point, hit.normal);
        if (hit.moveDirection.y > 0.01f)
            return;
    }
    float GetSpeed()
    {
        return moveSpeed;
    }

    public bool IsJumping()
    {
        return jumping;
    }

    bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return (collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.CollidedBelow) != 0;
    }

    Vector3 GetDirection()
    {
        return moveDirection;
    }

    public bool IsMovingBackwards()
    {
        return movingBack;
    }

    public float GetLockCameraTimer()
    {
        return lockCameraTimer;
    }

    bool IsMoving()
    {
        return Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")) + Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) > 0.5f;
    }

    bool HasJumpReachedApex()
    {
        return jumpingReachedApex;
    }

    bool IsGroundedWithTimeout()
    {
        return lastGroundedTime + groundedTimeout > Time.time;
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        gameObject.tag = "Player";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two lines under Update() that handle rotation:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
```

and

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(xzMove);
```

Follow the variables moveDirection and xzMove to see how the values are actually determined.  It should be pretty straight forward.  Hint: moveDirection located in the function UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection().  moveDirection is also used to calculate xzMove using movement.  The rest I leave up to you.

**Edit:** The section of code that actually processes movement is inside UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection().  Look down to if (grounded) --> if (targetDirection != Vector3.zero).  It is this area that processes movement.  It is the if (targetDirection < walkSpeed * 0.9f && grounded) where movement snaps at 90 degrees.  This is the intended function.

I swapped that code out with the code in the else statement, and at slow speeds the avatar moved more naturally.  The avatar will only walk at 45 degrees when either both horizontal and vertical are toggled simultaneously.  In other words, pressing up + left, or down + right, etc.

If you don't want the snap behavior, just use the code in the else statement and delete the conditional statements.  Then your avatar will always turn smoothly.

Comment: Hi memebrain  Thank's for your help

Actually movedirection values  determined  from vector3(private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;).I can't able to get what you mean.Here i have attached my source code link 

=========

https://ramesh950624@bitbucket.org/3rdperson/3rd.git

=========
can you please check it,if you are free.

Comment: I have edited my response after reviewing your project.  Anything other than what I discussed there would likely require writing a custom script.

I'd just like to note that your project is out of date.  I'm running 5.5, which is also out of date, but only recently.  I had to disable hud.cs in order to get your project to work.  Also, I'd like to point out Mechanim which does a much better job managing animations and character control.  It might behoove you to do a few tutorials. It will provide you much better results.

Comment: Hi,memBrain thanks for your support.This issue has been solved but it is not turning everytime 45degrees sometimes it is turning 60degress. could you help me on this regard.

Comment: As I said in my previous response, it will require a rewrite of the controller to get your desired functionality.  I'm in the middle of a reinstallation of my computer due to technical issues, so it will be a while before I can look at this again.  In the mean time, try experimenting with angular control.  For example, you can restrict the range of angular change by using a clamp on the values.  That way you can clam any rotation greater than 45 degrees to a maximum of 45 degrees.